# Getting "Invalid Integer Constant Expression" error when installing Caffe on Windows

Tags: python, deep-learning, caffe

I followed this video ([install Caffe on Windows](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ax9f1zQ_2l8)) to install `Caffe` on windows. When I run `scripts/build_win.cmd`, it reports an error:

```
 Invalid Integer Constant Expression
```

during the installation.

I am using `Windows 10`, `Microsoft Visual Studio 2015`. Because I have both `CUDA` 8 and `CUDA` 9 in my computer, and what I found was that during the installation, the system detects `CUDA` 9 instead of `CUDA` 8 (and I think `Caffe` does not support `CUDA` 9 on windows at the moment).

I wonder is there any system file that I could specify which `CUDA` to use (i.e. specify `CUDA` path?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should edit the file `Makefile.config` to change the CUDA path. Look for `CUDA_DIR :=` in that file to assign appropriate CUDA path.

Alternatively look for environment variable `CUDA_PATH` on your windows system and ensure that it's pointing to the CUDA version you want to use.